# Python:how to change variable at each iteration?

Tags: python, string, vector

I would like to be able to print a different variable present in the string "names" at each iteration of my cycle that contains the vector "numbers", in this way:

```
one x=1 y=2
two x=3 y=4
three x=5 y=6
four x=7 y=8
five x=9 y=10
```

how should I do it?
For the moment I was able to write only this part of the code:

```
numbers=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
names=('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')
for i in range (0, len(num)-1,2):
     x=numbers[i]
     y=numbers[i+1]
     print('x=', x, 'y=', y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that arrays start at 0, you could start with

`names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']`

The values inside `names` do not matter, but starting from `zero` helps.

Now you can see that what you want is, for every name, print the value it represents (`i`), then `2*i + 1` and `2*i + 2`:

```
zero   1  2
one    3  4
two    5  6
three  7  8
four   9  10
```

And as the values inside `name` do not matter, only their position, you can count again starting from `one`.

So this is my solution. Simple, and only three lines:

```
names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

for i in range (len(names)):
     print(names[i], 'x =', 2*i+1, 'y =', 2*i+2)
```

---

---

If you want to keep `numbers` or have minimal changes, here's a fix of Alessandro Artoni's answer:

```
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
names = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')

for i in range (0, len(names)):
     x = numbers[i]*2-1
     y = numbers[i]*2
     print(names[i], 'x=', x, 'y=', y)
```

---

---

Following your comment, this is how to output to a file:

```
names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range (len(names)):
         f.write(names[i] + '  x = ' + str(2*i+1) + '  y = ' + str(2*i+2) + '\n')
```

Or, since you chose tobias_k's answer:

```
numbers = range(1, 11)
names = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')
result = [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(names, zip(*[iter(numbers)]*2))]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for element in result
        f.write("%s  x=%d  y=%d\n" % element)
```

Comment: How do I create a text file (file.txt) and write my outputs there?

Comment: @luna8899 Edited my answer to add that

Answer (score 0):

The minimal changes to solve your question is this:

```
numbers=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
names=('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')
for i in range (0, len(names)):
     x=numbers[i]
     y=numbers[i+1]
     print(names[i], 'x=', x, 'y=', y)
```

I also suggest to you lists '[]' instead of tuples '()'. Enjoy!

Comment: How do I create a text file (file.txt) and write my outputs there?

Answer (score 0):

the desired output is:

```
one x=1 y=2
two x=3 y=4
three x=5 y=6
four x=7 y=8
five x=9 y=10
```

so I quickly put this together:

```
result = ""
max_number = 10

names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
y = 0
for i in range (1, max_number, 2):
    result +='%s x=%d y=%d\n' % (names[y], i, i+1)
    y += 1

print(result)
```

So basically I am concatenating each line and printing everything at the end. You could print as you go as well. What's left is to add some validation to make it robust :)

Comment: How do I create a text file (file.txt) and write my outputs there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `zip(*[iter(lst)]*n)` recipe to iterate pairs of values, and `zip` those with the names. (That first `zip` may seem a bit cryptic. Basically it creates an `iter` from the list, then `zips` two references of that iter together, resulting of pairs of consecutive elements.)

```
>>> numbers=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
>>> names=('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')
>>> [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(names, zip(*[iter(numbers)]*2))]
[('one', 1, 2),
 ('two', 3, 4),
 ('three', 5, 6),
 ('four', 7, 8),
 ('five', 9, 10)]
```

Once you have those tuples, you can use a format-string to print them (or write them to a file with `with open("name", "w") as f: for ...: f.write(...)`)

```
for t in [(a, *b) for a, b in zip(names, zip(*[iter(numbers)]*2))]:
    print("%s x=%d y=%d" % t)
```

Comment: How do I create a text file (file.txt) and write my outputs there?